# function template for string_view-to-integer conversion

Tags: c++, template, c++20

I want to make the following function a function template that supports all the integral types:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <charconv>
#include <string_view>
#include <concepts>
#include <limits>
#include <optional>

// header file

std::optional<int> to_integer( std::string_view token, const std::pair<int, int> acceptableRange =
                               { std::numeric_limits<int>::min( ), std::numeric_limits<int>::max( ) } ) noexcept;

std::optional<int> to_integer( const char* const token, const std::pair<int, int> acceptableRange =
                               { std::numeric_limits<int>::min( ), std::numeric_limits<int>::max( ) } ) noexcept = delete;


// source file

std::optional<int> to_integer( std::string_view token, const std::pair<int, int> acceptableRange ) noexcept
{
    if ( token.empty( ) )
    {
        return { };
    }

    if ( token.size( ) > 1 && token[ 0 ] == '+' && token[ 1 ] != '-' ) { token.remove_prefix( 1 ); }

    int value;
    const auto [ ptr, ec ] { std::from_chars( token.begin( ), token.end( ), value, 10 ) };

    const auto& [ minAcceptableValue, maxAcceptableValue ] { acceptableRange };

    if ( ec != std::errc( ) || ptr != token.end( ) ||
         value < minAcceptableValue || value > maxAcceptableValue ) { return { }; }

    return value;
}
```

Here is my version:

```
// header file

template < std::integral T >
std::optional<T> to_integer( std::string_view token, const std::pair<T, T> acceptableRange =
                               { std::numeric_limits<T>::min( ), std::numeric_limits<T>::max( ) } ) noexcept;

template < std::integral T >
std::optional<T> to_integer( const char* const token, const std::pair<T, T> acceptableRange =
                               { std::numeric_limits<T>::min( ), std::numeric_limits<T>::max( ) } ) noexcept = delete;


// source file

template < std::integral T >
std::optional<T> to_integer( std::string_view token, const std::pair<T, T> acceptableRange ) noexcept
{
    if ( token.empty( ) )
    {
        return { };
    }

    if ( token.size( ) > 1 && token[ 0 ] == '+' && token[ 1 ] != '-' ) { token.remove_prefix( 1 ); }

    T value;
    const auto [ ptr, ec ] { std::from_chars( token.begin( ), token.end( ), value, 10 ) };

    const auto& [ minAcceptableValue, maxAcceptableValue ] { acceptableRange };

    if ( ec != std::errc( ) || ptr != token.end( ) ||
         value < minAcceptableValue || value > maxAcceptableValue ) { return { }; }

    return value;
}


// call site

int main( )
{
    const std::string_view sv { "-100" };

    const auto retVal { to_integer<unsigned int>( sv, { 0, 100 } ) };

    std::cout << retVal.value_or( -1 ) << '\n';
}
```

1. Does my implementation have any flaws? Can it fail in some cases? How would you write it to make it better?
2. It somehow returns **4294967295** when passing e.g. **"-100"** as can be seen in the `main` function. Why? How can I fix that? I expect it to return an empty `optional` since **-100** is out of range of `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Don't delete the overload that takes a `const char*`

I don't understand why you delete the overload that takes a `const char*` as the first parameter. If you don't delete it, the one that takes a `std::string_view` is a viable candidate, because there is an implicit conversion from `const char*` to `std::string_view`. And it does exactly what you want.

## Consider removing the check for a leading `+`-sign

I would remove the check for a leading `+`-sign, and rely solely on `std::from_chars()` to determine the validity of the input. This makes your function behave more like other standard library functions, and thus avoids potentially surprising behavior. If you do need such functionality, consider putting it into a separate function, so the caller can choose whether to make use of that or not.

## The case of the return value 4294967295

This is not because of any flaw in `to_integer()`, rather it is because you are using `std::optional`'s [`value_or()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or). The `int` `-1` you pass in will be `static_cast`ed to the value type of the optional before it is returned. Since the value type is `unsigned int`, the `-1` will be converted to `4294967295`.

Comment: I deleted the `const char* const` overload since I wanted to prevent the user from passing in non-null terminated strings. Also I think `char*` overload is less efficient since it calls `strlen()` to determine the end of the string. And it fails when there is no '\0' at the right position.

Comment: "*Consider removing the check for a leading +-sign*", but I don't quite get why I should remove it. `from_chars` does not recognize the `+` character. So I have to remove it from the `string_view`.